# How can I populate data from an Excel worksheet to grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an application where I have to get email IDs from an Excel sheet and send out an email to each ID. I have tried to display the email IDs in a grid as a test. My application is not throwing any errors but it is not executing in the required manner.

Can anyone help figure out why this is happening?

Comment: First, how are you reading the Excel sheet?

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=138
This helped my requirement...good one

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code which binds Excel to a GridView:

http://www.shiningstar.net/ASPNet_Articles/DataSet/DataSetProject5.aspx

It may provide you with a neutral test harness.  Without your code and the spreadsheet it's hard to say what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The following link shows code how to extract data from required cells in an Excel sheet other than binding the whole excel sheet to a grid:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380

Also you can populate a DataTable using the selected values and then populate the DataGrid using that DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

```
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

             {

               if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                 {
                 Excel.Application appExl;
                 Excel.Workbook workbook;
                 Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
                 Excel.Range ShtRange;
                 appExl = new Excel.Application();


                / /Opening Excel file
                 workbook = appExl.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath("firstexcel.xlsx"));
                 NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
                 int Cnum = 0;
                 int Rnum = 0;

                  ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange; 

                //Reading Excel file.
                //Creating datatable to read the containt of the Sheet in File.
                  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                   dt.Columns.Add("EMP NO");
                  dt.Columns.Add("NAME");
                  dt.Columns.Add("AGE");
                  dt.Columns.Add("PHN NO");
                  dt.Columns.Add("EMAIL");

                 for (Rnum = 2; Rnum <= ShtRange.Rows.Count; Rnum++)
                     {
                       DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
              //Reading  Each Column value From sheet to datatable

              for (Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
                    {
                     dr[Cnum - 1] = (ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                    }
             // adding Row into DataTable
              dt.Rows.Add(dr); 
              dt.AcceptChanges();
                   }

              workbook.Close(true);
             appExl.Quit();
            //DataSource to GrigView
           gvOne.DataSource = dt;
           gvOne.DataBind();

             }

        }
```

Comment: try this code its wrkng fine for if u have any prblms u can feel free to ask..........
use these name spaces..
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data; 
&
click on reference in solution explorer and add reference (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)on clicking the .net tab

Comment: You do not want to use Office automation on a server, Microsoft explicitly states this fact.

Comment: @MarkSherretta: Have you got a link for that assertion?